# Get firebase server time cloud function

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a function that I can call on my iOS app to return me the current (or approximate) firebase server time.

I couldn't get any success with the following attempts. am I doing something wrong?

**Obs.:** The second one return an object of type *FIRHTTPSCallableResult* and I couldn't find a way to parse it, neither see the content into it to be sure if it worked.

```
exports.currentTime = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send({"timestamp":new Date().getTime()})
});

exports.currentTimeTwo = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {"timestamp":new Date().getTime()};
});

exports.currentTimeThree = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      const data = {"timestamp":new Date().getTime()}
    res.send(data)
});
```

iOS Code:

```
static func getServerTime(){
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("currentTimeTwo").call { (result, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("error \(error)")
              if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                print("error domain: \(error.domain)")
                let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                print("error code: \(code)")
                let message = error.localizedDescription
                print("error message: \(message)")
                let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                print("details: \(details)")
              }
            }
            print(result)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only the `functions.https.onCall` matches with the `Functions.functions().httpsCallable` in your Swift code, so the other ones are meaningless here. When you call that one, what are the values of `result` and `error` you get back?

Comment: Note that all [`FIRHTTPSCallableResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefunctions/api/reference/Classes/HTTPSCallableResult) contains is a `data` property that contains whatever your Cloud Function returns, as long as it's a valid JSON type, which your `new Date().getTime()` seems to be.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I didn't know that I should use the data property to access the content of the result. Now it's working fine with for functions.https.onCall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `functions.https.onCall` in your Cloud Functions code matches with the `Functions.functions().httpsCallable` in your Swift code, so the other ones are meaningless here.

When you call the `httpsCallable`, you get a [`FIRHTTPSCallableResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefunctions/api/reference/Classes/HTTPSCallableResult) whose `data` property contains whatever your Cloud Function returns, as long as it's a valid JSON type, which your `new Date().getTime()` seems to be

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.currentTimeTwo = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {"timestamp":new Date().getTime()};
  });
```

The function above is right. As Frank informed in the comments of my question, I was missing to access the property *data* from swift code  result.

New Swift Code:

```
static func getServerTime(){
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("currentTimeTwo").call { (result, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("error \(error)")
                if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                    print("error domain: \(error.domain)")
                    let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                    print("error code: \(code)")
                    let message = error.localizedDescription
                    print("error message: \(message)")
                    let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                    print("details: \(details)")
                }
            }
            let resultFireBase = result as! HTTPSCallableResult
            print(result?.data)
        }
    }
}
```